# Vue.js does not work when to call mix.react and mix.js using Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2

Vue.js does not work when to call `mix.react` and `mix.js` using Laravel Mix.

However, commenting out `mix.react` causes `Vue.js` to work properly.

Do you know why?

**WORK(webpack.mix.js)**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('src/resources/assets/vuejs/app.js', 'src/assets/js/vue_app.js');
// mix.react('src/resources/assets/js/app.js', 'src/assets/js/react_app.js');
```

- laravel-mix 2.1.11
- vue 2.5.16
- react 15.6.2

---

**Console log**

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src/resources/assets/vuejs/components/Notification.vue

**NOT WORK(webpack.mix.js)**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('src/resources/assets/vuejs/app.js', 'src/assets/js/vue_app.js');
mix.react('src/resources/assets/js/app.js', 'src/assets/js/react_app.js');
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <notification>
        slot message
    </notification>
</div>
{{ asset_js('vue_app.js') }}
</body>
</html>
```

**src/resources/assets/vuejs/app.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Notification from "./components/Notification.vue";
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {Notification},
});
```

**src/resources/assets/vuejs/components/Notification.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="notification">
        {{ body }}
        <p>
            <slot></slot>
        </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'notification',
        data() {
            return {
                body: 'I am a notification.'
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .notification {
        background: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I found a similar problem,
Temporarily changed mix.js to mix.react.
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1627